# Rotating a line around a circle

Tags: javascript, animation, math, canvas, geometry

I have two arcs with strokes and i want to have a line animate between them. The line should animate perpendicular to the points of the inner circle.

Here's something that I hacked together that is almost what I want.

things that are wrong with it are:

- the length of the line is not the length between the 2 circle as it revolves around the inner circle.
- sometimes the line is not perpendicular to the points of the inner circle. for example when it goes to the corner of the circle it tilts at an angle a little.

I had problem understanding how to use the trig function for `lineTo`. maybe because that changes the length of the line and I didn't know how to get the x and y coordinates of the outer circle to get the end point of the line. I'm used to doing `math.cos * length` and this gives me a line at an angle. I don't what a line I just wanted the coords of the outer circle.

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 function lineAtAngle(startX, startY, angleDeg, length, startX2, startY2, angleDeg2, length2){
   var angle = angleDeg * (Math.PI / 180);
   var angle2 = angleDeg2 * (Math.PI / 180);
   // context.moveTo(startX, startY);
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(
    Math.cos(angle) * length + startX,
    Math.sin(angle) * length + startY
    )
    context.lineTo(
    Math.cos(angle2) *(length2 )+ startX2,
    Math.sin(angle2)  *(length2) + startY2
    )
   // context.lineTo(canvas.width / 2 + 60, canvas.height / 2, angle2, length2)
   
   context.lineWidth = 10;
   context.stroke();
   context.closePath();
   console.log("startX2: " + startX2 + " startY2: " + startY2 )
   console.log(Math.sin(angle2) + startY2)
   console.log(length)
 }
 function myLineTo(startX, startY, angleDeg, length){

 }
 var length1 = canvas.width / 2 + 60 - canvas.width / 2 -30
 var length2 = canvas.width / 2 ;
 // var length2 = 1;
 console.log(length2)
 var angle1 = 0;
 var angle2 = 0;
 (function animate(){
  context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.stroke()

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.stroke();
  context.closePath()

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
  context.fill()
  context.closePath();
  angle1++
  angle2++
  // lineAtAngle(canvas.width / 2 , canvas.height / 2 , angle1, length1, canvas.width / 2 + 60, canvas.height / 2, angle2, length2 )
  lineAtAngle(canvas.width / 2 , canvas.height / 2 , angle1, length1, canvas.width / 2 + 60, canvas.height / 2, angle2, length2 )




 }())

}
```

```css
  canvas{
   background: #aaa;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: The angle problem is with canvas.width / 2 **+ 60**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea for drawing a line is that you need to supply a start point (`moveTo`), and an end point (`lineTo`).  Your current code is complicating the whole thing with multiple angles and lengths.  What you want to imagine you are doing is starting at the center of your circle, then adding an offset which places the start point at the edge of the inner circle.  Using trig is perfectly fine here.  The length of your line will simply be outer radius minus inner radius, in the same direction as your offset (only one angle was needed).

Without fundamentally changing your approach, the code below shows the changes you could use to try this.  Have your `line` function take a starting point (x, y) and an offset, as well as the angle and length.  The starting point is your circle center, and the offset is the radius of the inner circle.  The length (again) is simply the outer radius minus the inner radius.

```js
window.onload = function(){
   var innerCircleRadius = 30;
   var outerCircleRadius = 60;
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
   var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
   var angle1 = 0;
   function lineAtAngle(startX, startY, angleDeg, offset, length) {
      var angle = angleDeg * (Math.PI / 180); // Convert to radians.
      var cosAngle = Math.cos(angle); // Only need cos(angle) once.
      var sinAngle = Math.sin(angle); // Only need sin(angle) once.
      var startXPos = cosAngle * offset + startX; 
      var startYPos = sinAngle * offset + startY; 
      var endXPos = cosAngle * length + startXPos;
      var endYPos = sinAngle * length + startYPos;
      context.beginPath();
            
      context.moveTo(startXPos, startYPos);
      context.lineTo(endXPos, endYPos); 
   
      context.lineWidth = 10;
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
   }
   (function animate() {
   context.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   window.requestAnimationFrame(animate); 
   context.beginPath()
   context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, innerCircleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
   context.lineWidth = 1;
   context.stroke()

   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, outerCircleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
   context.stroke();
   context.closePath()

   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
   context.fill()
   context.closePath();
   angle1++
   lineAtAngle(canvas.width / 2 , canvas.height / 2 , angle1, innerCircleRadius, outerCircleRadius - innerCircleRadius);
   }())
}
```

```css
canvas {
   background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I am trying to implement the same using C language. But maths is not my cup of tea. Can you recommend some sources from where I can learn applied trigonometry? I always find theories but not applied real-life examples, so it's hard for me to actually implement it

Answer (score 2):

I believe the below is what you're trying to achieve.

I've simplified the code somewhat by using the Canvas's built-in methods to translate the coordinate space to the center and by removing the extra function which had way too many parameters passed when all it needed was one angle and two radii.

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

 var radius1 = 30;
 var radius2 = 60;
 var angle = 0;

 (function animate(){
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // save state and adjust coordinate space
  context.save();
  context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  context.lineWidth = 1;

  context.beginPath()
  context.arc(0, 0, radius1, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true)
  context.stroke()

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, radius2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(0, 0, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  context.fill()

  ++angle;
  var rads = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  var x = Math.cos(rads);
  var y = Math.sin(rads);

  context.lineWidth = 10;
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(radius1 * x, radius1 * y);
  context.lineTo(radius2 * x, radius2 * y);
  context.stroke();

  // restore transformations for next pass
  context.restore();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
 }())

}
```

```css
canvas { background: #aaa; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: While you have written good functional code, you really didn't address what the OP did wrong, or how to fix what they tried.

Comment: @StevenHansen that's because the original code was so confusing that it was hard to pin-point exactly where he did go wrong.

Comment: This is the functionality I was trying to achieve and thank you for the answer. But I wanted to experiment with trig functions. like access coordinates on the circle.

Comment: @jackblank fine - I'll update to use some trig instead of the rotation

Comment: I got it in my answer.  Trig is easy.  Each point on the circle is simply (startX + cos(angle) * radius, startY + sin(angle) * radius).  Have fun!

Comment: thanks but  keep this up too if you don't mind. I might want to use context.rotate() in the future if you didnt didn't delete all ready. Whatever.

Comment: @jackblank it was only a three line change

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I might start to use `context.translate` more because it looks like I won't have to use `startx` to calculate the offset from the center of the circle and for other stuff. I chose the other answer because that person helped me understand what I was I originally trying to do. This also helped me but in a different way.

Comment: p.s there's too many "closePath" calls there - they're only actually required if you want to attach the last point in the path explictly back to the first point.