# Rectangle is flipping and rotating. I just want it to rotate around a circle

Tags: javascript, animation, math, canvas, rotation

I don't know what I did wrong. I drew a rectangle using moveTo and lineTo because I wanted to make a shape similar to a rectangle. I just wanted to have the x and y coordinates of each corner move so that the rectangle could rotate between the two circles.

In the area where I have this type of code
`[Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius , Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius -5],` the -5s and +5s are for the width of the rectangle.when it starts, the width is 10px because its centered at the origin. I do the cos for the x coordinates and multiply that to the innerRadius or outerRadius depending on which coordinates are closer to the particular radius. I do the same for the y coordinates. Why does it flip ?

I originally wanted to make the rectangle shape similar to the lights on the Simon Says toy.The one where it lights up and you tap on the lit ones. Could you help me make that shape with the moveTo, LineTo so that that shape can be rotating. the coordinates on the topRight and the bottomRight should have a greeter distance between them then the other 2.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


  var innerRadius = 30;
  var outerRadius = 60;
  var wCenter = canvas.width/2;
  var hCenter = canvas.height/2



  var angle = 0;
  function rectangle(topLeft,topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft){
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(topLeft[0],topLeft[1]);
    context.lineTo(topRight[0],topRight[1]);
    context.lineTo(bottomRight[0], bottomRight[1]);
    context.lineTo(bottomLeft[0],bottomLeft[1]);
    context.fillStyle = "tomato";
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }
  var num;
  var otherNum;
  (function animate(){
    console.log("TEst")
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
    context.save();
    context.translate(wCenter, hCenter)
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(0,0,outerRadius,0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fillStyle = "orange"
    // context.fillStyle="white"
    context.fill();
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(0,0,innerRadius,0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fillStyle="white"
    context.fill()

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle="tomato";

    rectangle(
      [Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius , Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius -5],
      [Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * outerRadius,   Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * outerRadius  -5], 
      [Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * outerRadius, Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * outerRadius +5],
      [Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius, Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius  + 5])

    --angle
    context.stroke()
    context.closePath();

    context.restore()
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }())

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

The base rectangle has the points [innerRadius, -5] [outerRadius, -5] [outerRadius, 5] [innerRadius, 5]

Now you want to rotate it around the origin so you multiply each point with the rotation matrix [ [cos, sin] [-sin, cos] ].

It seems like you just rotated the center point and not the entire shape.

Below is the corrected code.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


  var innerRadius = 30;
  var outerRadius = 60;
  var wCenter = canvas.width/2;
  var hCenter = canvas.height/2



  var angle = 0;
  function rectangle(topLeft,topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft){
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(topLeft[0],topLeft[1]);
    context.lineTo(topRight[0],topRight[1]);
    context.lineTo(bottomRight[0], bottomRight[1]);
    context.lineTo(bottomLeft[0],bottomLeft[1]);
    context.fillStyle = "tomato";
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  }
  var num;
  var otherNum;
  (function animate(){
    console.log("TEst")
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
    context.save();
    context.translate(wCenter, hCenter)
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(0,0,outerRadius,0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    context.fillStyle = "orange"
    // context.fillStyle="white"
    context.fill();
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(0,0,innerRadius,0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fillStyle="white"
    context.fill()

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle="tomato";

    rectangle(
      [Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius - Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 5 , -Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius - Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 5],
      [Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * outerRadius - Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 5 , -Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * outerRadius - Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 5], 
      [Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * outerRadius + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 5, -Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * outerRadius + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 5],
      [Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 5, -Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * innerRadius + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * 5])

    --angle
    context.stroke()
    context.closePath();

    context.restore()
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }())

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't think it would be that complicated that I would have to use a matrix. I never used one so I don't understand this.  I wanted a simple answer like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34451129/rotating-a-line-around-a-circle   this but i guess since there are 8 coordinates It gets more complicated so a matrix is more important. Is that a reason for using the matrix? ** when you say:  ** "It seems like you just rotated the center point and not the entire shape." Do you mean the center point of the rect. I meant to rotate all points.